# How to test an Activity that uses a ContentProvider without affecting production database?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, android-testing, android-contentresolver, abstract-factory

**THE PROBLEM**

I have two Android classes that I want to test:

- `CommentContentProvider`, which extends [`ContentProvider`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html) and is backed by a [SQLiteDatabase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html).
- `CommentActivity`, which extends [`Activity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) and accesses `CommentContentProvider` indirectly through a [`ContentResolver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html).

I currently have two test classes:

- `CommentContentProviderTest`, which extends `ProviderTestCase2<CommentContentProvider>` and uses a [`MockContentResolver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/mock/MockContentResolver.html).  This works fine.
- `CommentActivityTest`, which extends `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<CommentActivity>`.  This works fine, except for the parts of `CommentActivity` that access `CommentContentProvider`.

The problem is that, when `CommentActivity` accesses `CommentContentProvider`, it does so through the standard `ContentResolver`:

```
ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();
Cursor cursor = resolver().query(...);
```

Thus, when `CommentActivityTest` is run, it launches `CommentActivity`, which accesses (read and write) the production database, as shown in the above two lines.

My question is how to make `CommentActivity` use the standard `ContentResolver` in production but `MockContentResolver` during test.

**RELATED QUESTIONS**

- This differs from [Android unit testing with ContentProviders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8825644/android-unit-testing-with-contentproviders?rq=1) and other questions I've found about testing ContentProviders because those can extend android.test classes designed for testing ContentProviders while I need to extend a class for testing an `Activity`.
- This is similar to [How to inject a dependency when testing an Android activity without a third-party framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22121911/how-to-inject-a-dependency-when-testing-an-android-activity-without-a-third-part), which was also posted by me but is unanswered.  I am now willing to use a third-party framework if it will help.
- [Query using MockContentResolver leads to NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22443259/query-using-mockcontentresolver-leads-to-nullpointerexception) is related and leads to the  solution in Option 1 below, but I do not know if it is the best solution in my case.

**POSSIBLE SOLUTIONS**

It would be nice if I could inject a `ContentResolver` (possibly a `MockContentResolver` or `RenamingDelegatingContext`) through the [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) that starts `CommentActivity`, but I can't do that, since [`Context`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html)s are not [`Parcelable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html).

Which of the following options are best, or is there a better option?

*OPTION 1*

Add a debug flag to the `Intent` that starts `CommentActivity`:

```
public class CommentActivity extends Activity {
    public static final String DEBUG_MODE = "DEBUG MODE";
    private ContentResolver mResolver;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        :
        // If the flag is not present, debugMode will be set to false.
        boolean debugMode = getIntent().getBooleanExtra(DEBUG_MODE, false);
        if (debugMode) {
            // Set up MockContentResolver or DelegatingContextResolver...
        } else {
            mResolver = getContentResolver();
        }
        :
    }
```

I don't like this option because I don't like to put test-related code in my non-test classes.

*OPTION 2*

Use the abstract factory pattern to pass a `Parcelable` class that either provides the real `ContentProvider` or a `MockContentProvider`:

```
public class CommentActivity extends Activity {
    public static final String FACTORY = "CONTENT RESOLVER FACTORY";
    private ContentResolver mResolver;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        :
        ContentResolverFactory factory = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(FACTORY);
        mResolver = factory.getContentResolver(this);
        :
    }
```

where I also have:

```
public abstract class ContentResolverFactory implements Parcelable {
    public abstract ContentResolver getContentResolver(Context context);
}

public abstract class RealContentResolverFactory extends ContentResolverFactory
    public ContentResolver getContentResolver(Context context) {
        return context.getContextResolver();
    }
}

public abstract class MockContentResolverFactory extends ContentResolverFactory
    public ContentResolver getContentResolver(Context context) {
        MockContentResolver resolver = new MockContentResolver();
        // Set up MockContentResolver...
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

In production, I pass in (via an intent) an instance of `RealContentResolverFactory`, and in test I pass in an instance of `MockContentResolverFactory`.  Since neither has any state, they're easily Parcelable/Serializable.

My concern about this approach is that I don't want to be ["that guy"](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=that%20guy) who overuses design patterns when simpler approaches exist.

*OPTION 3*

Add the following method to `CommentActivity`:

```
public void static setContentResolver(ContentResolver) {
  :
}
```

This is cleaner than Option 1, since it puts the creation of the `ContentResolver` outside of `CommentActivity`, but, like Option 1, it requires modifying the class under test.

*OPTION 4*

Have `CommentActivityTest` extend `ActivityUnitTestCase<CommentActivity>` instead of  `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<CommentActivity>`.  This lets me set `CommentActivity`'s context through [`setActivityContext()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/ActivityUnitTestCase.html#setActivityContext%28android.content.Context%29).  The context I pass overrides the usual `getContentResolver()` to use a `MockContentResolver` (which I initialize elsewhere).

```
private class MyContext extends RenamingDelegatingContext {
    MyContext(Context context) {
        super(context, FILE_PREFIX);
    }

    @Override
    public ContentResolver getContentResolver() {
        return mResolver;
    }
}
```

This works and does not require modifying the class under test but adds more complexity, since [`ActivityUnitTestCase<CommentActivity>.startActivity()` cannot be called in the `setUp(`) method, per the API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/ActivityUnitTestCase.html#startActivity%28android.content.Intent,%20android.os.Bundle,%20java.lang.Object%29).

Another inconvenience is that the activity must be tested in touch mode, and [setActivityInitialTouchMode(boolean)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.html#setActivityInitialTouchMode%28boolean%29) is defined in `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<T>` but not `ActivityUnitTestCase<T>`.

FWIW, I am being a little obsessive about getting this right because I will be presenting it in an Android development class I am teaching.

Comment: I am confused about how option 2 works. How is the actual factory selected in prod vs test?

Comment: @NamshubWriter, thanks for reading.  I added to the question: In production, I pass in (via an intent) an instance of RealContentResolverFactory, and in test I pass in an instance of MockContentResolverFactory.  Since neither has any state, they're easily Parcelable/Serializable.

Comment: There is a small spelling error. In option 2 getContextResolver should be getContentResolver.

Comment: In the same situation. I like option 3, but unfortunately keeping that in a static field leads to memory leaks (as warned in AS 2.2)

Comment: @EllenSpertus: Did you ever settle on a good solution?

Comment: @MWB No, I haven't.

Comment: @EllenSpertus: I just posted a question of my own on the subject: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52905933/test-method-that-uses-contentprovider

Answer (score 1):

Option 2 seems best to me. I'm not bothered about the use of a factory; I'm more bothered by the intent causing a change in behavior at a distance. But the other solutions put non-production code in the production code, so what you are testing isn't much like how things work in production. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  The silence had been deafening. :-)